# Insufficient Storage Available when installing Google Play Services

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have rooted my Kindle Fire 7 (4th Generation) and installed Gapps using the Jmz Fire HD7 Tool. Everything went well, but, when I was trying to start Gmail, it asked me to update my Google Play Service. When the installation was nearly finished, a message "Insufficient Storage Available" popped up.

What can I do? I have tried to clear all data and force stop Google Play Service, and it still can't be updated. Any help would be appreciated.

## EDIT

Pasting the result of `df` here... looks no good.

```
Filesystem               Size     Used     Free   Blksize
/dev                   435.9M   288.0K   435.6M   4096
/sys/fs/cgroup         435.9M    12.0K   435.8M   4096
/mnt/asec              435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/mnt/obb               435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/storage/usbotg        435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/storage/emulated      435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/mnt/secure            435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/mnt/asec              435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/mnt/obb               435.9M     0.0K   435.9M   4096
/system                  1.1G     1.1G    23.9M   4096
/cache                 852.4M   483.7M   368.7M   4096
/data                   12.3G     1.3G    11.0G   4096
/mnt/sqfs              124.6M   124.6M     0.0K   32768
/persistbackup          10.8M   184.0K    10.6M   4096
/mnt/shell/emulated     12.3G     1.3G    11.0G   4096
```

Comment: How much available storage does it have?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard This is very funny. I have 10.78GB free storage left. It could fit 50 Google Play Service in it.

Comment: I'm thinking the partition that hold Google Play Services is much smaller or there is a problem with write privileges.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I'd like to know how I can see the size of that partition...

Comment: Install SystemPanelLite or SystemPanel by NextApp; either will show you the size of all easily accessible partitions.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard take a look at the result... hmm... 23.9M left? What can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31910/discussion-between-jamie-and-rockpaperlizard).

Answer (score 0):

1. First, turn off power on and off your phone and see if the problem still exist . If so,
2. Go to your storage usage located in your settings and try deleting one unimportant app
3. If steps #1 or #2 didn't work or go through, just simply unmount the SD card the correct way. *Don't just pull it out*. If you have been doing this, it is probably why it's doing that now.
4. If you have done these steps, it should work. If not, go to a little side store that fix phones or the mall. You can also go to your service provider and see if they can fix the problem. Otherwise, go to amazon.com and look up SD card installment kit and you should be able to pick which one you want from them.

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. I removed the signature because this site is a Q&A site, not a social forum. If you want to be contacted, you can put your contact on "About Me" on your profile.

Comment: I can tell you that I have already done all above before you answered; I even deleted several (unimportant) system apps so the remaining space is about ~130 MB; but I still can't update the Google Play Service. BTW, my Fire is Fire HD 7 (4th Generation) with no SD slot.